# Angular 2 Animations will not work

Tags: angular, animation, typescript, components, templating

Following the Angular 2 Documentation for Animations (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html) I migrated to Angular 4.0.1. Here's a part of my package.json:

```
"@angular/common": "~4.0.1",
"@angular/compiler": "~4.0.1",
"@angular/core": "~4.0.1",
"@angular/forms": "~4.0.1",
"@angular/http": "~4.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.1",
"@angular/router": "~4.0.1",
"@angular/animations": "~4.0.1",
"typescript": "^2.2.2",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
```

**system.config.js**

```
  '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
  '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
  '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
  '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
  '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
  '@angular/router/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-upgrade.umd.js',
  '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
  '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
  '@angular/upgrade/static': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js',
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
...
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, appRouting, FormsModule ],
...
})
```

Inside my custom component I also imported the angular animation:

```
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';
```

And my view (external view assigned by templateUrl!) looks like this:

```
<div class="container" [@containerState]="showContainer">
...
</div>
```

**The problem is: I always get a console error message:**

*Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Found the synthetic property @containerState. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application.*

When I remove this synthetic property everything works fine, but I'm not able to use Angular Animations.

Any ideas? I do not use angular-cli!

---

**Update container.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, EventEmitter, HostListener, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';
@Component({
    templateUrl: '...',
    selector: '...',
    animations: [
        trigger('containerState', [
            state('hide', style({transform: 'translateY(-102%)'})),
            transition('hide => show', [
                animate(500, style({transform: 'translateY(0)'}))
            ]),
            transition('show => hide', [
                animate(500, style({transform: 'translateY(-102%)'}))
            ])
        ])
    ]
})
```

---

**Currently its running...**

What I did? Deleted the complete node_modules folder and running a clean install. After that everything works fine. Very strange! I will try to upgrade another Angular 2.x app to Angular 4.x

Comment: I see all the necessary pieces except the component,  `@Component({ animations:[  trigger('containerState', [ state('*',  .  . .  . ` ,  also I'm not sure `@angular/animations/browser` is necessary.

Comment: Also check if you got into this "misleading error message" problem. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15581

Comment: I checked everything. I also downloaded the example from Angular 2 Animations documentation: [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html), copied my component and everything works fine. Finally it works after deleting the complete node_modules folder and running a clean install.

Answer (score 1):

Angular2 considers the prefix '@' to represent a 'synthetic listener' which should be overridden by the animations module you specify. However, you're using the @ symbol yourself, `<div class="container" [@containerState]="showContainer">`

Try removing the '@' and seeing if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I incorrectly specified `animations` property in the `@Component(...)` directive. I had smth like:

```
@Component(
...
animations: [ 
   { provide: Class, useValue: ... }
]
...
)
```

Check that you don't have anything expect animation in the animations array.
Hope it helps someone.